# Is pthread_mutex_lock required for thread functions which have local variables?

Tags: linux, pthreads

It is a universal fact, that pthread_mutex_lock( ) should always be applied for global and static variables used in thread functions. How about local variables inside thread functions?

What are the usecases, in which a local variable inside a thread function should be locked OR should it be always locked?

Example:

```
int func( void )
{
  int var;
  var++; // What are the usecases in which this should be locked?

}

pthread_create(&threadid1, NULL, func, NULL);
pthread_create(&threadid2, NULL, func, NULL);
```

Comment: as far as I know, you can build multithreaded applications on fences, mutex and/or atomics, so your "universal fact" it's more like an opinion.

Comment: You should use mutex lock for variables that are used in more than one thread. If you access your local variable (somehow) from two threads - use mutex_lock(). Othrewise no.

Comment: More correctly threading primitives should be accessible from multiple threads. How you achieve this is up to you. global and static scoping are just two ways that can be achieved. Conversely locking CAN only be useful in cases where the subject of the lock is accessible by another thread. However it is in my opinion, although it IS possible to share variables without using global/static scoping, it is not desirable due to the principle of least surprise.

Comment: In answer to your OP, normally you would NOT need to. However, if at any point in your function you pass control of the variable (by ref) outside of the scope of the function into another thread, then you may want locking. However your code would not be communicating the scope of the variable effectively. In other words, Normally No. You could create cases where you Do, but that would make you a horrible human being.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, stack variables can be safely accessed from your thread, even if you use the same function to start multiple threads.

Each thread has its own stack, so each time you start it there'll be a separate instance of 'int var'.

The usual restrictions do apply of course. If you somehow share 'var' accross multiple threads you still need to protect it, but there's no kind of implicit or automatic sharing for stack variables.

Comment: How about calling pthread_create inside func( ) and passing var as a thread data?

Comment: So, taking the above case, we can't make a universal rule that no local variables should be protected, yeah, and i think you pointed out that - `if you somehow share 'var' accross multiple threads you still need to protect it`